# How do you pronounce "Lakitu"?

Tags: mario-series

Lakitus are one of the most iconic characters in the world of *Super Mario* that can be best described as:

> *...bespectacled Koopas who ride clouds through the skies. ...best known for tossing Spiny Eggs to Mario or Luigi below.*

Source: [Lakitu - Super Mario Wiki](http://www.mariowiki.com/Lakitu)

[image]

However, I have noticed that there seems to be several different pronunciations in use for their names.

For example:

- /läki:tu/ —  *law-kee-tu*
- /lɐki:tu/ —  *luh-kee-tu* (The one I use.)
- /lækɪ:tu-/—  *la-ki-tu* (Commonly used on internet.)
- /lækiːtu/ —  *la-kee-tu*

...just to name a few of the many possible combinations.

Is there any official consensus on how the name of these characters is pronounced?

Comment: There is no utility whatsoever behind this question.  Either way, Arqade isn't about official consensus, so I've voted to close as primarily opinion based.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question if it asks not for consensus but for an official (according to Nintendo) pronunciation. Currently it asks for an "official consensus". I'm not sure what that would be.

Comment: @Frank: There are a [quite few questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=pronounce) like this on the site already, and [even a meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3214/are-pronunciation-questions-out-of-scope) about it. Opinions seem somewhat mixed, but the general consensus is that these fall within our scope.

Comment: @Peeja Asking for official information is actually off-topic here, due to Arqade not being a news site.  All we'd be doing is repeating what's already been said, and we've decided that doesn't play to our expertise.  Essentially, if it happens in-game, it's allowed.  Things not in-game, generally not.  There are exceptions, but that's the general rule of thumb.

Comment: Voting to keep this open, it is a genuine question and requesting knowledge on a subject of gaming which can't have a bias opinion also the question is asking what is the correct pronunciation of the name, side question which doesn't have to be answered was if there is a official pronunciation @Frank I see you're point though how is can partially be opinion based due to the mixture of pronunciation's on the web and how people commonly say it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Princess Toadstool pronounced it in the television show /ˈlækiːtuː/ (la-KEE-too)

http://www.mariowiki.com/lakitu

[image]

As that page states and if you ever watched the show you would have heard this being used, but like it says "(la-KEE-too)" is western

It maybe pronounced different in other regions

If you are looking for official I'm guessing this is one of the closest you'll get because it was spoken/pronounced like this in an official production of a Mario title

Comment: FYI 'læ' is like the 'la' in 'land', not the 'la' in 'large'

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft there's a difference in land and large? (not a native english speaker)

Comment: @JohnDemetriou - I know this is an older post, but the a in "large" is softer, like you're saying "ahhhhh" when a doctor checks out your throat during a checkup. In "land", it's *sort of* like the "wah" sound a baby makes when crying (minus the "w" of course). I know these aren't perfectly accurate descriptions, and I'm not well-versed in language terminology at all, but this is the best I can convey as a native English speaker :)

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading in Nintendo Power years ago... la-KEE-too is correct.

Answer (score 0):

My friend used to pronounce it like  'luh-koo-too', though I have heard it as 'lah-ki-tu' (lah as in laugh). I myself have always pronounced his name         'lay-kit-oo'. (tho when I was little, I said lay-ki-choo, the 'ki' NOT sounding like 'key')